# Data of type undefined has no value?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, type "undefined" is supposed to have one value "undefined". However, in this example below, an undeclared xxx has type "undefined" but apparently it has no value of any kind. It does not make any difference that JS throws an exception because of no value in xxx. To be consistent JS should throw an exception on typeof xxx. Otherwise, we have a big hole in logic here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
document.write("Type=" + typeof xxx);
document.write(", Value=");
document.write(xxx);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question does not make sense; `undefined` is not a "type".

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-typeof-operator - So as per the spec, if the variable is unresolvable then `undefined` is returned, not an error, but if you are trying to get the value of a variable and it is unresolvable then `ReferenceError` is thrown - So there is no problem there

Comment: Right well it's a "type" in the low-level language semantics sense, but it's not a "type" in the sense of actual JavaScript programming types. In any case, [11.4.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3) is the answer to the question. The `typeof` operator explicitly returns `undefined` when its operand is unresolvable.

Comment: It's not a big hole, it is a good way to test if a variable is defined or not (so that you can avoid the crash you get when trying to do anything with it).

Comment: 4.3.10 undefined value
4.3.11 Undefined type

Comment: 4.3.10 undefined value
4.3.11 Undefined type

Comment: your response of full of contradictions. "undefined" is a type and value

Comment: Your question is a form of, "why is JavaScript defined the way it is?", and that is not considered constructive or useful on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Clearly, you do not have a sufficient understanding of the topic. "undefined" is a type with one value "undefined", read your own link to see the confirmation. Which part of the logic you fail to understand?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first look at:

- [Data Types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures)
- [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

---

In your example you never actually declare `xxx` as a variable, therefore when you `document.write(xxx)` the variable `xxx` doesn't exist.

```
var xxx;
document.write("Type=" + typeof xxx);
document.write(", Value=");
document.write(xxx);
```

Declaring `var xxx;` with no value will instantiate it and since it has no value assigned, the default assignment will be `undefined` as stated in the [data types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures).

Comment: The question does not ask why xxx is undefined. The question asks why undefined/undeclared xxx has type "undefined" while it has no value even though the specs say clearly 
4.3.10 undefined value
primitive value used when a variable has not been assigned a value
4.3.11 Undefined type
type whose sole value is the undefined value

Comment: @JohnLopui the `typeof` function evaluates it as `undefined`, what that means is that it is actually declaring/instantiating it as a variable when you run `typeof` but it's not saving it in that scope so when it finishes it garbage collects and is gone, so there is no memory reference of the variable `xxx` ever existing, when you call it in `document.write` at the bottom.